# How do I build SDL_TTF?

Tags: c++, windows-vista, makefile, sdl

Okay, so I'm on Windows Vista, and I want to use SDL_TTF, but the idiots who made it decided you have to build everything from source, so I to build the .lib files and all that other stuff, but I'm on Windows, so how am I suppose to do this?

Comment: Looks like Win32 binaries are available to me: http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

Comment: The idiots who made it happen to be Sam Lantinga, author of SDL and one of the greats in the games industry. Also its what's called free software, who do they think they are to give it to you for free without shining your shoes into the bargain?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you looked, but the SDL_TTF page have precompiled win32 binaries,
http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/ , or more specifically, http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL_ttf-devel-2.0.10-VC.zip

Answer (score 2):

Well bad news for Windows user you will get "unresolved external symbol _TTF_GetFontOutline" or "unresolved external symbol _TTF_SetFontOutline". Both function are NOT INCLUDED with the Windows lib of this version. (But the dll does). So you may need to compile them.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) to build autotools-based projects like SDL and its associated libraries.

SDL_TTF also provides a Visual Studio project in `VisualC.zip`.